# Run VBA through specific range

Tags: excel, vba

I got this code, but it only works for one line.

How to make it run on entire column?

```
Public Sub StripLastName()

Dim strLastName As String

strLastName = Range("A2")
strLastName = Right(strLastName, 8)
strLastName = Trim(strLastName)

Range("C2") = strLastName

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make it a For Loop.

```
Dim strLastName As String
dim i as long
dim lastrow as long

    lastrow = Range("A" & rows.count).End(xlup).Row

        for i = 2 to lastrow

            strLastName = Range("A" & i)
            strLastName = Right(strLastName, 8)
            strLastName = Trim(strLastName)

                Range("C" & i) = strLastName

        Next i 

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution without loop:

```
Public Sub StripLastName()

    Dim strLastName As String
    Dim LastRow As Long

    'Create a with statement including the worksheet you want work with
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        .Range("C2:C" & LastRow).Formula = "=TRIM(RIGHT(OFFSET(C2,0,-2),8))"

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm trying to split line adresses in two. for example ; 122 4e blue street, I would like to strip the "4e blue street".

Comment: @SandraGevio tha initial question request for another solution and my answer best on the question